# how to create view and get data mysql php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have database 'testdatabase' and want to create a view having column 'value' from table 'testtabl'e , then want to sum the rows in value of view created before . Then store it in javascript array . I have put on this code but not able to know where I am making mistake . It does not show any thing not even a blank messagebox.

```
<script>



    var data=[
    <?php


$connection =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");

mysql_select_db("testdatabase");

$query = mysql_query("CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT value FROM testtable") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_fetch_array($query);

$r2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) FROM view1;") or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r2))
 {
       echo $row['value'].',';
     }
     ?>];


    window.alert(data);
    </script>
```

Comment: If you can, you should stop using mysql_* functions. They are officially deprecated. These extensions have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about prepared statements instead, and consider using PDO, it's really not hard.

Comment: but for the time , I am stuck with this need to finish the job through mysql only

Comment: But MySQL is vulnerable and pdo isn't. Why should you use MySQL?

Comment: Because I have it in my requirment document , it needs to be done through it

Comment: [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html) is not hard to do.

Comment: I am not able to get any column in view , testtable has columns 'value' and 'mark' both are int datatype

Comment: I know that you likely have a MySQL database. You *use* PDO with the MySQL database. When the `mysql_*` API disappears all of the clients queries will stop working.

Comment: Is your file a PHP or a Javascript file? You have php codes nested inside `<scrip>` tags, they won't get executed if your file is a javascript file. Check your browser's console for possible Javascript errors.

Comment: But there are opening and closing PHP tags @NaijaProgrammer - it looks ok.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, what I meant is that if the file is saved with a ".js" extension, then the server will do nothing with the PHP codes.

Comment: JS is JS, PHP is PHP; why are you structuring such as lethal cocktail?

Comment: Thank you guys for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the returned column changes when you add the function to it. Forcing the declared name 'as value' should work:

```
"SELECT SUM(value) as value FROM view1;"
```

Complete answer:

```
<script>
var data=[
<?php


$connection =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");

mysql_select_db("testdatabase");

$query = mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS SELECT value FROM testtable") or die(mysql_error());

$r2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) as value FROM view1;") or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r2))
 {
   echo $row['value'].',';
 }
 ?>];


window.alert(data);
</script>
```

Comment: The name of the returned column changes? Where is *that* in the docs? *"By default, the names of the columns retrieved by the SELECT statement are used for the view column names."* from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: It's part of mysql. You asked for SUM(value) not value. Thus the name of the returned column is called 'SUM(value)', but you can supply an alias with 'as'.

Comment: The first fetch_array should be removed. There will not be a resource returned from the query, only a boolean. It may also be worth adding a check that the view already exists as MySQL will throw an exception if it exists already.

Comment: I removed the extra fetch instruction , and tried the code only with php and echo it on page but it shows this error '$connection' (T_VARIABLE)' I think this might be the reason but have no clue why is it showing it

Comment: That points to a syntax error (missing quote, etc.). Try this: `<script>
var data=[<?php
$connection =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("testdatabase");
$query = mysql_query("DROP VIEW view1") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT value FROM testtable") or die(mysql_error());
$r2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) as value FROM view1;") or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r2)){echo $row['value'];}
?>];
    window.alert(data);
    </script>` If it doesn't work please update your code.

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments - edit your original post to make changes.

Comment: :) Depending on where this will run, you can remove the complete line with the 'DROP' query and make your Create View query: 'CREATE OR REPLACE view view1 as select value from testtable'. This way it will always work regardless of whether the view exists in the first place.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sorry, didn't realize the formatting would be so bad in the comment. I will do that from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're nesting PHP code in a JavaScript function which is a really bad idea. You will get errors that will be hard to track down if you continue to code like that. If you need data in your JavaScript you can output the PHP result or use AJAX to retrieve the value.

Here is an example that keeps things much cleaner:

```
<?php
$connection =mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("we couldn't connect!");
mysql_select_db("testdatabase");
$query = mysql_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS SELECT value FROM testtable") or die(mysql_error());
$r2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value) as value FROM view1;") or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($r2); // there is only one result
?>

<script>
    var data = [ <?php echo $result['value']; ?> ];
</script>
```

As stated in comments, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and have been removed in PHP 7. Anyone using PHP should learn how to use prepared statements with the MySQLi API or, preferably, the PDO API. The added benefit to using prepared statements is the prevention of SQL Injection attacks.

Second, 'value' is a MySQL [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). You should change the name of the column. If you insist on keeping the column that name you will have to use back ticks to differentiate it:

```
CREATE VIEW `view1` AS SELECT `value` FROM `testtable`

SELECT SUM(`value`) FROM `view1`
```

In addition, there is no need to fetch an array after the first query, where you create the view. You are not using the result of the `CREATE` anywhere.

Comment: Ok now I have tried to run the code just on php and echo result on page , but it shows this error 'syntax error, unexpected '$connection' (T_VARIABLE)' I think this might be the reason but have no clue why is it showing it

Comment: You really shouldn't 'nest' PHP in JavaScript like that. Start with a PHP only page.

Comment: Yes I am using now PHP only page , but the error resides yet '$connection' (T_VARIABLE)' why is it giving this

Comment: Thanks Jay for your reply